# Background running time with PushKit VoIP notifications

Tags: ios, pushkit

I'm writing VoIP application that uses PushKit notification, and I can't found **what amount of background execution time gives me one incoming push?**

The first thing I've checked is `[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining` but this counter doesn't reset by next pushes and apps still remain active even with `backgroundTimeRemaining == 0`.

My question is how to get remain time until app become frozen by system? Or how to calculate this time in respect to number of incoming PushKit pushes.

I need this to gracefully close sockets/connections before application becomes frozen.

Comment: related developer forums post https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28019 
which is currently unanswered, but the poster has some personal measurements. i.e. initially 30 seconds, but this can change when receiving a second (or third) notification while still processing the first.